# Accessing other files in various locations inside a given file?

Tags: python, import, directory, subdirectory, sys

I have the following folder structure (this was given to me and is expected to remain, so I cannot reorganize anything).

```
Folder1
    Folder2.py
        File1
        Folder3
            File2.py
            File3.py
```

I am working in File2, and want to import functions/classes from File1 and File3 inside File2. I tried doing `from Folder1.Folder2.File1 import Class1` and `from Folder1.Folder2.Folder3.File3 import Func1`. If I am in terminal and changed my directory to Folder3 so I can just run `python File2.py` from terminal, how do I properly import from File1.py and File3.py? Should I run the file differently in terminal? Right now I am getting the error `No module named Folder1`. Essentially I want to access 1) a file inside a folder one level up (File1) and 2) a different file inside the same level (File3). How do I do this? Since I don't work a ton with terminal, I would love as specific instructions as possible and please use the structure/naming I provided if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this is in Linux, then you can do something like this in a file env.py and import the file at the starting point of your program call and then you can normally import File1..etc without any hazzles

```
import os
import sys
root_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(root_path, 'Folder1'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(root_path, 'Folder1', 'Folder2'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(root_path, 'Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3'))
```